# Web scraping with R (rvest)

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest, sapply

I'm new to R and am having some trouble to create a good web scraper with R.... It has been only 5 days since I started to study this language. So, any help I'll appreciate!

#### Idea

I'm trying to web scraping the classification table of "Campeonato Brasileiro" from 2003 to 2021 on Wikipedia to group the teams later to analyze some stuff.

#### Explanation and problem

I'm scraping the page of the 2002 championship. I read the HTML page to extract the HTML nodes that I select with the "SelectorGadget" extension at Google Chrome. There is some considerations:

1. The page that I'm trying to access is from the 2002 championship. I done that because it was easier to extract the links of the tables that are present on a board in the final of the page, selecting just one selector for all (tr:nth-child(9) div a) to access their links by HTML attribute "href";
2. The selected CSS was from 2003 championship page.

So, in my twisted mind I thought: "Hey! I'm going to create a function to extract the tables from those pages and I'll save them in a data frame!". However, it went wrong and I'm not understanding why... When I tried to ran the "tabelageral" line, the following error returned : "Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"". I think that it is reading a string instead of a xml. What am I misunderstanding here? Where is my error? The "sapply" method? Since now, thanks!

#### The code

```r
library("dplyr")
library("rvest")

link_wikipedia <- "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campeonato_Brasileiro_de_Futebol_de_2002"
pagina_wikipedia <- read_html(link_wikipedia)

links_temporadas <- pagina_wikipedia %>%
  html_nodes("tr:nth-child(9) div a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  paste("https://pt.wikipedia.org", ., sep = "")


tabela <- function(link){
  pagina_tabela <- read_html(link)
  
  tabela_wiki = link %>%
    html_nodes("table.wikitable") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    paste(collapse = "|")
}
tabela_geral <- sapply(links_temporadas, FUN = tabela, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
tabela_final <- data.frame(tabela_geral)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the Final classification table? Is the table a) present for all years b) in same format? Can you show 2 rows of the expected output format e.g. how one should handle the country flag info and whether one should repeat `Classificação ou rebaixamento` across merged rows?

Comment: My main subject is to merge all tables to aggregate the following columns: position, club (without the flags), goals, goals against and goal balance. I have an idea to implement it directly, but I need to check it. This is my first "project" applying to R. I know it is a simple project to those that have some experience, but it is a huge step for me... ^^

Comment: May not be that simple for anyone depending on what you want. This, for me, was the missing piece of a well written question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` to target the appropriate table by class and then a substring that the table contains. Furthermore, you can use `html_table()` to extract in tabular format from matched node. You can then subset on a vector of desired columns. I don't know the correct football terms so have guessed the columns to subset on. You can adjusted the `columns` vector.

If you wrap the years and constructed urls to make requests to inside of a `map2_dfr()` call you can return a single `DataFrame` for all desired years.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

years <- 2003:2021
urls <- paste("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campeonato_Brasileiro_de_Futebol_de_", years, sep = "")
columns <- c("Pos.", "Equipes", "GP", "GC", "SG")

df <- purrr::map2_dfr(urls, years, ~
read_html(.x, encoding = "utf-8") %>%
  html_element('.wikitable:contains("ou rebaixamento")') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[columns] %>%
  mutate(year = .y, SG = as.character(SG)))
```

Comment: Wow! This is really advanced for me, I think. I appreciate your answer and your time, and I'll certainly study your code! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the tables from those links by doing this:

```
tabela <- function(link){
  read_html(link) %>% html_nodes("table.wikitable") %>% html_table()
}

all_tables = lapply(links_temporadas, tabela)
names(all_tables)<-2003:2022
```

This gives you a list of length 20, named `2003` to `2022` (i.e. one element for each of those years).  Each element is itself a list of tables (i.e. the tables that are available at that link of `links_temporadas`.  Note that the number of tables avaialable at each link varies.

```
lengths(all_tables)
2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 
   6    5   10    9   10   12   11   10   12   11   13   14   17   16   16   16   16   15   17    7
```

You will need to determine which table(s) you are interested in from each of these years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @langtang! Actually, I realize that I was using tabela_wiki <- link ~~~ instead of tabela_wiki <- pagina_tabela ~~~. It would never read the HTML from the page because of that. But I think that your solution is better than mine, since it seems to be more quick. I want to access the table that is preceded by an h2 tag "classificação". I'll try that now... If you have any idea about how can I do it, I'll appreciate that! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. It's more complicated than your function because those pages have more than one table so the function returns only the tables with a column names matching `"Pos."`.

Then, before `rbind`ing the tables, keep only the common columns since the older tables have one less column, column `"M"`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library("dplyr")
  library("rvest")
})

link_wikipedia <- "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campeonato_Brasileiro_de_Futebol_de_2002"
pagina_wikipedia <- read_html(link_wikipedia)

links_temporadas <- pagina_wikipedia %>%
  html_nodes("tr:nth-child(9) div a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  paste("https://pt.wikipedia.org", ., sep = "")


tabela <- function(link){
  pagina_tabela <- read_html(link)

  lista_wiki <- pagina_tabela %>%
    html_elements("table.wikitable") %>%
    html_table()

  i <- sapply(lista_wiki, \(x) "Pos." %in% names(x))
  i <- which(i)[1]
  lista_wiki[[i]]
}

tabela_geral <- sapply(links_temporadas, FUN = tabela, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

sapply(tabela_geral, ncol)
#>  [1] 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
#sapply(tabela_geral, names)

common_names <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(tabela_geral, names))
tabela_reduzida <- lapply(tabela_geral, `[`, common_names)

tabela_final <- do.call(rbind, tabela_reduzida)
head(tabela_final)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 12
#>    Pos. Equipes       P         J     V     E     D    GP    GC SG      `%`
#>   <int> <chr>         <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int>
#> 1     1 Cruzeiro      100      46    31     7     8   102    47 +55      72
#> 2     2 Santos        87       46    25    12     9    93    60 +33      63
#> 3     3 São Paulo     78       46    22    12    12    81    67 +14      56
#> 4     4 São Caetano   742      46    19    14    13    53    37 +16      53
#> 5     5 Coritiba      73       46    21    10    15    67    58 +9       52
#> 6     6 Internacional 721      46    20    10    16    59    57 +2       52
#> # ... with 1 more variable: `Classificação ou rebaixamento` <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To have all columns, including the `"M"` columns:

```
data.table::rbindlist(tabela_geral, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: What a great answer, Rui! There was a lot of things that I don't understood bc I never saw it, but I'll search those methods... Thanks!

Vlw msm, Rui! Vai me ajudar bastante no aprendizado procurar alguns dos métodos que tu colocou na resposta. Gratidão! ^^